# Codeigniter: Display a controller's output in a Div

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, controller

I currently open a pop-up window, when a button is clicked.

The url passed is a controller, whose result is a chart image (the code to display the chart is written in the controller itself; there's no view).

How should I display the controller's output inside a div ? I no longer want to show a popup.

Here is my Javascript to invoke the chart-controller:

```
var newUrl = BASEURLINDEX + "/"+controller+"/index/"+studentid+"/"+class_level+"/"+"0"+"/"+resultid;

var left = (screen.width/2)-(700/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(500/2);

var myWindow = window.open(newUrl, "MsgWindow", "width=700, height=350, left=250, top=200");
```

And here is my chart-controller, that is opened in the Pop-Up window:

```
function index($studentid="",$level="",$exam_level="", $resultid="")
{           
    $combined = $this->database_connectivity($studentid, $exam_level, $resultid);

    /* Draw the line chart */
    $myPicture->drawLineChart();

    /* Write the chart legend */
    $myPicture->drawLegend(540, 20, array("Style" => LEGEND_NOBORDER, "Mode" => LEGEND_HORIZONTAL));
}
```

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

Euh... Write the div tag inside the controller or just use a view (that would clean up your code....)

;-)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I didn't put it properly. From page A, I invoke another controller, and display it in a pop-up. Now getting rid of the pop-up, how to display the controller's output in a div of page A itself ? (we're doing this to avoid user clicks and a pop-up increases clicks)

Comment: Are there two separate controllers? Else you could just invoke the chart method inside the page method. Not sure how it would work if you want to invoke the method from a different controller. Lastly you could just place the logic of the chart in the method of the page. As i said earlier it is handy to place the output in a view so that you can load multiple views

Comment: Bob, well the chart-controller is in PHP, whereas the parametrs it accepts are user generated (Javascript). So that's why I earlier took params from the page and invoked chart-controller in a Pop-up. As you suggested, I'll try multiple views on the same page i.e. inside a <div> I'll try to load chart-controller......let's see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to have the output in a separate view.

As you might know, you can load multiple views in a controller.

If you want you can put everything in one controller method which you can call from other methods. This method would handle the logic and the view load

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I didn't put it properly. From page A, I invoke another controller, and display it in a pop-up. Now getting rid of the pop-up, how to display the controller's output in a div of page A itself ? (we're doing this to avoid user clicks and a pop-up increases clicks)